# Calculate average ticket response time

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get average response time for a department.

Below is my database schema.
Tickets:

```
| ID   | Subject   | Department  | AdminId  | ClientId  | created_at          |
| 1    | Test1     | 1           | 0        | 1         | 2015-01-01 10:10:10 |
| 2    | Test2     | 1           | 0        | 2         | 2015-01-01 20:20:20 |

TicketReplies:
  --AuthorType:
    ----1 => Admin
    ----2 => Client



| ID   | TicketId   | Body        | AuthorId  | AuthorType | created_at          |
| 1    | 1          | Test Body?  | 1         | 2          | 2015-01-01 10:10:10 |
| 2    | 1          | Yes!        | 1         | 1          | 2015-01-01 10:48:16 |
| 3    | 2          | Are you Ok? | 2         | 2          | 2015-01-01 20:20:20 |
| 4    | 2          | Yes!        | 1         | 1          | 2015-01-02 08:15:18 |
```

Comment: Check out GROUP BY, with AVG.

Comment: You have to provide your definition for `average response time` some say response time is how long  take answer the first call . So is `Time of First Response - Time of First Call` other say is how long take to solve so is `Time of Last Response - Time of First Call`

Answer (score 0):

The average response time is the maximum time minus the minimum divided by the total number of responses minus one.

To get the value in seconds:

```
select t.department,
       ( (to_seconds(max(created_at)) - to_seconds(min(created_at)) ) /
         nullif(count(*) - 1, 0)
       )
from ticketreplies tr join
     tickets t
     on tr.ticketid = t.id
group by t.department;
```

This works in MySQL 5.5+.  In earlier versions, you can do the same thing by converting to a Unix timestamp.

Comment: Can you really calculate average response time like that?

Comment: Where you get that definition for `average response time`?

Comment: Hmmm, I was assuming that the average time was the average time between tickets.  Perhaps that is not the right definition.

Answer (score 0):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd34b8/3)**

```
SELECT Department, AVG(response_time) as avg_response  -- in seconds
FROM 
    (
    SELECT T.Department, 
           TR.TicketId,
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(TR.created_at), MAX(TR.created_at)) as response_time
    FROM Tickets T
    JOIN TicketReplies TR
      ON T.id = TR.TicketId   
    GROUP BY T.Department, TR.TicketId
    ) as T
GROUP BY Department
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Department | avg_response |
|------------|--------------|
|          1 |        22592 |
```